# What should I do to contact HR if a job posting is no longer available?

Tags: job-search, human-resources, applications

A job posting closed while I was filling out my online application. I saved a draft of the application because I was waiting for a letter of recommendation from my previous boss.

When I picked up where I left off, I discovered the posting was no longer available. The deadline for the job posting wasn't visible.

I have already applied to other jobs, but there might be a very slim chance with this one. I still have my draft and it includes the job posting title and job number. With this information, what is the best way to contact HR about the job posting?

Answer (score 5):

> With this information, what is the best way to contact HR about the job posting?

If there was a "very slim" chance with this company, I think the best thing to do is **move on with your job-hunt**. Insisting on this one may not be worth your time.

You missed the deadline, visible or not, and insisting on them receiving an extra-official application may be a bit unprofessional, not to mention they may not be able to do it even if they wanted to (company policies).

I'd still suggest you salvage what you can from that draft, in case anything you wrote the documents you got could be useful in future applications.

Comment: +1.  Companies can (and do) pull job listings.  Could be that you didn't get the application in on time.  Or, the company could have pulled the listing for other reasons - position no longer needed, budgetary reasons, they might have implemented a hiring 'freeze', etc.  DC is correct - chalk this up to experience and move on.

Answer (score 5):

> With this information, what is the best way to contact HR about the
>   job posting?

Call and ask if the job is still open.

It can't hurt anything, and will only take a few minutes of your time.

Comment: +1 also a valid option :) (I'd even say to try this before my answer) worth noticing that calling to ask if the job is still open is different than calling to ask for them to consider your application extra-officially... the latter should be avoided, but the first surely won't hurt